# Testing model saving using devise

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a form that accepts up to 20 questions at a time.  It takes in an array and saves the questions to the database.  Every question has 4 answers.  I can save the questions to the database just fine.  But, I'm running into issues linking them to a user.

Here is the controller:

```
  class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @question_group = []
    20.times do
      @question_group << Question.new
    end
  end

  def create
      params["questions"].each do |question|
        # If the question is empty, we don't want to save it
        if !question_empty?(question) 
          current_user.questions.create!(question_params(question))
        end
      end
    flash[:success] = "Quiz made!"
    redirect_to root_url

  end
```

It fails the following test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateQuestionsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:cookie)
  end


  test "should save the right amount of questions" do 
    post user_session_path, :user => {:email => @user.email, :password =>  @user.password} 
    get new_question_path
    assert_difference 'Question.count', 1 do
      post questions_path, {"questions" => [{"question" => "What is 1+1?",
                           "a1" => "0", "a2" => "1", "a3" => "2", "a4" => "3"}]} 
    end
    assert_difference 'Question.count', 2 do
      post questions_path, { "questions" => [{"question" => "What is 1+1?",
                           "a1" => "0", "a2" => "1", "a3" => "2", "a4" => "3"}, 
                           {"question" => "What is 1 - 1?", "a1" => "1",
                           "a2" => "0", "a3" => "2", "a4" => "3"}]} 
    end
  end 

end
```

In the test above, the question(s) aren't being saved.  This works in manual testing, but I can't build an automated test for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change a little bit about the model design. Instead of handling arrays. I would create a parent object like `QuestionForm` accepting nested forms:

```
class QuestionForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
   #your reject validations here
 }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and then in your `Question` model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question_form
end
```

then you test the `QuestionForm` flow (with the nested questions)

Sorry but it didn't answer your question, just a tip ;)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that at first, but if like to be able to create a pool of questions that can be placed in different groups. I'm not sure if  nested attributes can help me or not. I'll have to read up on it. Thanks!